Indy UDP Server can't send back to sender via router
Using Delphi 7, for testing purposes I have a TIdUDPClient app and TIdUDPServer app.  I send text from the client to the server, and the server sends a response string back.
This works perfectly on PCs across a local LAN, but when the server is on a dedicated Windows Server elsewhere, the UDP server receives the text but fails to send a response back with a Socket Error 10054, Connection reset by peer.
The firewall on the server allows all outgoing connections, and incoming on 9999. I thought routers allowed return communications on UDP within a time interval.  Is that not the case?
Client code
UDPClient.Host := 'myserver.com';
UDPClient.IP := 9999;
UDPClient.Send('Hello');
Memo2.Text := UDPClient.ReceiveString(3000);

Server code
UDPServer.DefaultPort := 9999;
UDPServer.Active := True;

procedure TForm1.UDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  Memo1.text := BytesToString(AData);
  ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,'Received: '+Memo1.Text);
end;


The code shown is fine, so the problem has to be in the networking. Did you try running a packet sniffer on both ends and make sure packets are actually present on both PCs?

No, but I don't see the point... "Hello" is arriving at the server, but the server cannot send anything back, as it gets a socket error.  Presumably the router is not allowing it for some reason?

You didn't say which side is getting the error. For UDP, a "connection reset by peer" error means a previous send had replied with a "host/port unreachable" ICMP error. Which again, indicates a networking problem.

UDP is a connectionless protocol, there is no session established between client and server. In this case the client's router must be setup to forward all packets on port 9999 to the client's IP address.

Remy, it is the UDP Server that gets the socket error when trying to send the response back.  I've heard others on this forum getting responses back through a router using UDP.  Apparently routers should temporarily keep track of outgoing data in the NAT table and allow a response within a time frame, but I guess this router doesn't do it.

whosrdaddy, it's not port 9999 the response is being sent back to.  The router has allocated a random port number as the originating port, and this appears in the PeerPort field on the packet received at the server.

Not all routers keep track of UDP connections so you will need to find another way.

@Ross as I said earlier, the code shown is correct, the problem is with the networking, getting the reply packet delivered from the server PC to the client PC. It is getting blocked somewhere and not able to reach the client. As this is not a coding problem, try asking on [sf] or Network Engineering
